# detect the minimization of an app

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I'm trying to make a tweak that will enable/disable rotation lock on the launching/closing of twitter, I got the launching and rotation lock part working with "launchFromLocation" and "SBOrientationLockManeger" but i cant seem to find or understand a way to detect when I minimize twitter (IE press home button).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should be able to swizzle the application's delegate to fire your code on [`applicationDidEnterBackground:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground).

Comment: yes applicationDidEnterBackground is a perfect solution, but how would i implement it, i believe i would have to hook twitters app delegate but i dont know how to do that.